# How to copy certificate files from local Java KeyStore to Docker image/container/pod?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, google-bigquery

I am building a Spring Boot REST API that connected to a BigQuery backend to fetch data. The app works fine on my local. When I deploy it to a lower environment, I get the below error when I access an endpoint.

```
Error getting access token for service account: Connection reset, iss: <>.iam.gserviceaccount.com] with root cause
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113) ~[google-http-client-1.40.0.jar!/:1.40.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84) ~[google-http-client-1.40.0.jar!/:1.40.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012) ~[google-http-client-1.40.0.jar!/:1.40.0]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:602) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:243) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:240) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) ~[guava-30.1.1-jre.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$AsyncRefreshResult.executeIfNew(OAuth2Credentials.java:567) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.asyncFetch(OAuth2Credentials.java:206) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:156) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:1022) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:96) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159) ~[google-cloud-core-http-2.1.2.jar!/:2.1.2]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:91) ~[google-http-client-1.40.0.jar!/:1.40.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:404) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar!/:1.32.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar!/:1.32.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar!/:1.32.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar!/:1.32.1]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.create(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:218) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$5.call(BigQueryImpl.java:374) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$5.call(BigQueryImpl.java:371) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105) ~[gax-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76) ~[google-cloud-core-2.1.2.jar!/:2.1.2]
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50) ~[google-cloud-core-2.1.2.jar!/:2.1.2]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.create(BigQueryImpl.java:370) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.create(BigQueryImpl.java:345) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
```

This exception occurs when the application tries to authenticate to Google Service Account.

```
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(bigQueryApplicationProperties.getProjectId()).setCredentials(GoogleCredentialsUtility.getCredentials(googleCredentials)).build().getService();
```

GoogleCredentials is the properties file that has all the Private Key, auth uri, project id etc.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "google.bigquery.credentials")
public class GoogleCredentials {

    private String type;
    private String project_id;
    private String private_key_id;
    private String private_key;
    private String client_email;
    private String client_id;
    private String auth_uri;
    private String token_uri;
    private String auth_provider_x509_cert_url;
    private String client_x509_cert_url;

}
```

On local machine, I have certificate files on the local Java KeyStore path - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security.

How do I place the same files on the Docker Image/Container/Pod for the application to be able to authenticate to Google Service Account?

Answer (score 0):

It is required to add the certificate to your Dockerfile. It will add the certificate to your docker image:

```
WORKDIR /opt/workdir/
#.crt file in the same folder as your Dockerfile
ARG CERT="star.crt"

#import cert into java
COPY $CERT /opt/workdir/
RUN keytool -importcert -file $CERT -alias $CERT -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
```